# Empty box instead of hieroglyphic numeral and `\mathabx`

Tags: xetex, packages, itemize, hieroglf

I have **hieroglyphic numerals** defined in my `package.sty`
but starting with 14071 this gives an emptybox instead off the numeral itself.
Something is wrong but I do not know what.
I've aksed this question [elsewhere](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511864/empty-box-instead-of-hieroglyphic-numeral) but now the problem is different: it involves `\usepackage{mathabx}`.
When I comment out `\usepackage{mathabx}` the numerals appear again.
But then I get from `\ggg` this >>> and not this >>.

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{mathabx}

%\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

%\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
%\usepackage{unicode-math}
\let\circ\undefined
\let\diamond\undefined
%\let\bullet\undefined
\let\ring\undefined
%\let\emptyset\undefined
%\let\owns\undefined
\usepackage{mathabx}

%\usepackage{xypic}

\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{mypackage}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcommand{\pullbackcorner}[1][dl]{\save*!/#1-1pc/#1:(1,-1)@^{|-}\restore}
 

\usepackage{babyloniannum}
%\setfont{NewGardiner}
\newfontfamily\ngg{Segoe UI Historic}[Ligatures=TeX]

 
\MakeRobust\babyloniannum
\MakeRobust\hgnum
\usepackage{enumitem}


 
\begin{document}
$\ggg$


\underline{motto:}{ každý den $\pm$ nový princip }\hfill{$\square$}
\bigskip
\bigskip
 \begin{enumerate}[ label=\roman{enumi}--\arabic{enumi}--\!\!\!\!\!\babyloniannum{\value{enumi}}\!\!\!--\large\ngg\symbol{\numexpr "13000+\value{enumi}}--\hgnum{\theenumi}]
  \item rozhodovat se na hraně zajímavého
  \item *vždycky to tam máš (data v matematice)
  \item svoboda a volnost
 
%\newcommand{\demoletter}[1]{{\setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}\fbox{\phantom{#1}}}}

\item \hgnum{1070}
\item \hgnum{1081}

\item \large\ngg\symbol{\numexpr "13000+1070}
\item \large\ngg\symbol{\numexpr "13000+1071}
\item \large\ngg\symbol{\numexpr "13000+1072}
\item \large\ngg\symbol{\numexpr "13000+1073}
\item \large\ngg\symbol{\numexpr "13000+1074}
\item \large\ngg\symbol{\numexpr "13000+1075}
\item \large\ngg\symbol{\numexpr "13000+1076}
\item \large\ngg\symbol{\numexpr "13000+1077}
\item \large\ngg\symbol{\numexpr "13000+1078}
\item \large\ngg\symbol{\numexpr "13000+1079}
\item \large\ngg\symbol{\numexpr "13000+1080}
\item \large\ngg\symbol{\numexpr "13000+1081}

  \item teorie množin (a někdy i další) je manipulace s objekty "ode zdi ke zdi" a jejich sledování
   
\end{enumerate}



\end{document}
```

mypackage.sty

```
% this is my first package
%
% (c) Buffalo Bill
%
%% This program can be redistributed and/or modified under the terms
%% of the LaTeX Project Public License Distributed from CTAN archives
%% in directory macros/latex/base/lppl.txt.
%
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}
  [2011/01/11 v0.01 LaTeX package for my own purpose]

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\hg{Segoe UI Historic}

\def\hgunits#1{\ifcase#1\relax\or
^^^^^^0133fa\or
^^^^^^0133fb\or
^^^^^^0133fc\or
^^^^^^0133fd\or
^^^^^^0133fe\or
^^^^^^0133ff\or
^^^^^^013400\or
^^^^^^013401\or
^^^^^^013402\else
?\fi}

\def\hgtens#1{\ifcase#1\relax\or
^^^^^^013386\or
^^^^^^013387\or
^^^^^^013388\or
^^^^^^013389\or
^^^^^^01338a\or
^^^^^^01338b\or
^^^^^^01338c\or
^^^^^^01338d\or
^^^^^^01338e\else
?\fi}

\def\hghundreds#1{\ifcase#1\relax\or
^^^^^^013362\or
^^^^^^013363\or
^^^^^^013364\or
^^^^^^013365\or
^^^^^^013366\or
^^^^^^013367\or
^^^^^^013368\or
^^^^^^013369\or
^^^^^^01336a\else
?\fi}

\def\hgthousands#1{\ifcase#1\relax\or
^^^^^^0131bc\or
^^^^^^0131bd\or
^^^^^^0131be\or
^^^^^^0131bf\or
^^^^^^0131c0\or
^^^^^^0131c1\or
^^^^^^0131c2\or
^^^^^^0131c3\or
^^^^^^0131c4\else
?\fi}

\def\hgtenthousands#1{\ifcase#1\relax\or
^^^^^^0130ad\or
^^^^^^0130ae\or
^^^^^^0130af\or
^^^^^^0130b0\or
^^^^^^0130b1\or
^^^^^^0130b2\or
^^^^^^0130b3\or
^^^^^^0130b4\or
^^^^^^0130b5\else
?\fi}

\def\hghundredthousands#1{\ifcase#1\relax\or
^^^^^^013190\or
^^^^^^013190^^^^^^013190\or
^^^^^^013190^^^^^^013190^^^^^^013190\or
^^^^^^013190^^^^^^013190^^^^^^013190^^^^^^013190\or
^^^^^^013190^^^^^^013190^^^^^^013190^^^^^^013190^^^^^^013190\else
?\fi}


\DeclareRobustCommand\hgnum[1]{{\hg\expandafter\hgnumx\the\numexpr20000000+#1\relax}}

%\def\hgnum#1{{\hg\expandafter\hgnumx\the\numexpr10000000+#1\relax}}
\def\hgnumx#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8{%
\hghundredthousands{#3}%
\hgtenthousands{#4}%
\hgthousands{#5}%
\hghundreds{#6}%
\hgtens{#7}%
\hgunits{#8}%
}


%\RequirePackage{whateverwe need}
\def\hi{Hello, this is my own package}
\let\myDate\date
\newcommand\GoodBye[1][\bfseries]{{#1Good Bye}}

\endinput
%%
%% End of file `mypackage.sty'.
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your MWE does not compile, because it needs an additional file `babyloniannum.sty`.

When I delete all the Bablylonian, the problem is with the commands such as

```
\large\ngg\symbol{\numexpr "13000+1070}
```

You define `\ngg` in your document as the Babylonian cuneiform font, but you seem to want to use it for Egyptian hieroglyphs.  Additionally, you are setting it outside any group, so it bleeds through and also changes the font of the surrounding text.  What you want is something like

```
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\largehg}{\large\hg}
```

Followed by

```
\item \largehg{\symbol{\numexpr "13000+1070}}
```

I do have a Windows machine with Segoe UI installed, and perhaps some of your examples would work with it, but many are not valid Unicode at all.  To get your example to compile on this machine, I instead loaded

```
\newfontfamily\hg{Aegyptus}[
  Scale=MatchUppercase,
  Script={Egyptian Hieroglyphs},
  UprightFeatures={Ligatures=Common}]
```

Where you can download the font [from its webpage.](https://dn-works.com/ufas/)  Note that version 13.00 has a non-free license that restricts it to “personal use.”

Your problem does not seem to be directly related to `mathabx`, but don’t load `mathabx`.  It’s buggy and obsolete.  If you really must, load it after `amssymb` and before `accents`.  That’s the order that doesn’t give you error messages about commands already being defined.  You seem to have loaded `unicode-math` at some point and then commented it out.  That is a much better idea.

Finally, it’s a very good idea to add the line `\tracinglostchars=2` at the top of your document.  This will print a warning message when a font does not contain a character, and tell you which character it was trying to load from which font.

Comment: Can you please provide me with MWE for your  `\newfontfamily\hg{Aegyptus}[
  Scale=MatchUppercase,
  Script={Egyptian Hieroglyphs},
  UprightFeatures={Ligatures=Common}]` ? I.e. one where 1071 and following work ?

Comment: I was able to get the first of them to work, but the rest don’t seem to be the codepoints of hieroglyphs at all.

Comment: @user2925716 [Here is a solution I posted last year.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/511390/61644)